# Water damaged passport with all the data pages perfectly alright

Tags: visas, air-travel, passports, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

[image]

I have tickets booked tomorrow for Bangkok where my uncle works and my passport got water damaged today. However my data pages are flawless. Tourist Visa needs to be applied on arrival. Will there be any problem on arrival to Thailand.? Please suggest some way if it is going to be a problem. I can’t even apply for Tatkal as it’s not possible to get it in a day.. please suggest..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Unfortunately, we cannot give you a definitive answer as to whether the damage is significant or not, as we do not know what standards will be applied by either the airline or by immigration personnel, and much may be left to the judgment of individual agents or officers. At this point, there is little to do but try.

Comment: Were you able to travel with water damaged passport?

Answer (score 2):

One of my friend washed his jeans with his Passport in the pocket. It looks worse than yours, but he had no problem while travelling from Germany to Serbia, which is not in EU.

Comment: I agree. This looks fine.

Comment: I've had the same issue also, roughly 3 times as bad as the photo from falling out of a canoe. No problems.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.. they haven’t even opened the front page. I got to know that as long as your details page is safe it would do.